# Ubuntu 12.04 is throwing segmentation fault on every command in terminal, also often suddenly going to login screen

Tags: 12.04, xorg, openbox

I am running openbox. What ever command i apply it keep saying "Segmentation fault" and then often sometimes going back automatically to the ubuntu login screen even its mentioned to use openbox only.

[image]

giving strange command outputs and not taking any commands.

```
sun@e700gent:~$ sudo init 6
sun@e700gent:~$ sudo init 6
sun@e700gent:~$ sudo init 6
sun@e700gent:~$ sudo init 6
Segmentation fault
sun@e700gent:~$ sudo init 6
sun@e700gent:~$ sudo init 6
sun@e700gent:~$ sudo init 6
Segmentation fault
sun@e700gent:~$ sudo init 6
Segmentation fault
sun@e700gent:~$ sudo init 6
Segmentation fault
sun@e700gent:~$ sudo init 6
Segmentation fault
sun@e700gent:~$ sudo init 6
Segmentation fault
sun@e700gent:~$
```

How do i fix it?

EDIT: RAM?

```
Handle 0x000F, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000D
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 2
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MHz
    Manufacturer: Hynix/Hyundai
    Serial Number: 23392095
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: HMT351U6CFR8C-PB  
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MHz
```

Comment: Have you checked your RAM?

Comment: RAM is fine and yes it was not 99% used mostly it get used like 40% maximum. e.g: Mem:   3938328k total,  1725972k used,  2212356k free,   143016k buffers

Comment: @LiveWireBT: RAM checked and edited above please see. 4GB RAM not full used.

Comment: I thought of something like memtest, but since you run a VM, broken RAM might not be the issue and the host should show the same issues.